# cross domain mp3 opera extension

Tags: jplayer, opera-extension

I'm having trouble playing mp3 files served from a remote domain in an Opera extension. I'm using jPlayer. Is it at all possible to play mp3 from another domain in Opera. Because as far as i know Opera only supports mp3 in flash, but flash probably has some cross domain restrictions. So if it is possible what steps should I take and how to make jPlayer (or maybe an alternative player) work in Opera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've never played with that but have you tried to apply the policy file? http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: I do not have control over domain that hosts mp3s so using content policy file is not really an option

Comment: We are currently working on support for native MP3 playing so Flash will not be needed. It should solve your problem soon.

Answer (score -1):

will this make the following code *stream* instead of just downloading?

```
<td style="text-align: left;" valign="top"><a href="test-clip.mp3">
```